# Correct Way to Call InputBox with Async/Await in VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In a VS Code extension I'm writing, I am trying to understand the right way to use an async function with an await in order to get data from an inputbox presented to the user.

The main part of my code that isn't working as I thought it would:

```
function runGitConfigCheck() {
    console.log('\nChecking for .gitconfig file');
    let requiredgitTags = ['user', 'http', 'https', 'core'];
    let requiredgitConfigItems = 
    [
    'http.sslbackend=thebestSSLofcourse',
    'http.proxy=http://myproxy.website.example:1234',
    'https.proxy=http://myproxy.website.example:1234',
    'http.sslcainfo=C:\\Users\\myusername\\path\\to\\folder'
    ];
    /** 
        TODO: other things here
     */

    let gitConfigExists: boolean = checkFileExistsInTargetFolder(userProfile, '\\.gitconfig');
    if (gitConfigExists === false) {
        // create new empty git config
        fs.appendFileSync(userProfile + '\\.gitconfig', '');
        requiredgitConfigItems.forEach(function (value) {
            console.log('Writing value to config: ' + value);
            fs.appendFileSync(userProfile + '\\.git', '\n' + value);
        });
    }
    else if (gitConfigExists === true) {
        console.log('.gitconfig file found');
        var gitconfig = ini.parse(fs.readFileSync(userProfile+"\\.gitconfig",'utf-8'));
        let attributes = getGitConfigAttributeNames(gitconfig);

        // check for the [user], [http], [https], and [core] attributes
        let tagsNotFound = new Array();
        let tagsFound = new Array();

        for (var tag in requiredgitTags) {
            let tagValue = requiredgitTags[tag];
            console.log('searching for tag '+tagValue);
            let search = searchForGitTag(tagValue, attributes);

            if(search === true) {
                tagsFound.push(tagValue);
            }
            else {
                tagsNotFound.push(tagValue);
            }
        }

        addGitTagsNotFound(tagsNotFound, userProfile+'\\.gitconfig');

        console.log('Finished doing all the things!');
    }   
}


function appendItemsToConfigFile(file: fs.PathLike, configItems: string[], firstItemStartsNewLine?: boolean)
{
    let counter: number = 0;
    configItems.forEach(function (item) {
        if(firstItemStartsNewLine === true && counter === 0) {
            fs.writeFileSync(file, `\n${item}\n`, {encoding: 'utf-8', flag: 'as'});
        }
        else {
            fs.writeFileSync(file, `${item}\n`, {encoding: 'utf-8', flag: 'as'});
        }
        counter++;
    });
    return;
}

async function getUserInfo(myplaceholder: string) {
    let userInputWindow = vscode.window.showInputBox({ placeHolder: myplaceholder, prompt: 'Here is the prompt' });
    return userInputWindow;
}

function addGitTagsNotFound(tags: string[], configFile: fs.PathLike) {
    tags.forEach(function (tag) {
        switch(tag) {
            case 'user':
                let currentName = getUserInfo('Message1')
                .then(function (result) {
                    return result;
                });
                let currentEmail = getUserInfo('Message2')
                .then(function (result) {
                    return result;
                });
                console.log(currentEmail + ' ' currentEmail);
                break;
            case 'http':
                console.log('Adding config items for [http] tag');
                appendItemsToConfigFile(configFile, [`[${tag}]`,
                                                    '\tsslBackend=myconfig',
                                                    `\tsslCAInfo=${userProfile}\\path\\to\\folder`,
                                                    '\tproxy=http://myproxy.website.example:1234'], true);
                break;
            case 'https':
                console.log('Adding config items for [https] tag');
                appendItemsToConfigFile(configFile, [`[${tag}]`,
                                                    `\tsslCAInfo=${userProfile}\\path\\to\\folder`,
                                                    '\tproxy=proxy=http://myproxy.website.example:1234'], true);
                break;
            case 'core':
                console.log('Adding config items for [core] tag');
                appendItemsToConfigFile(configFile, [`[${tag}]`,
                                                    `\teditor=${userProfile}\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe -w`], true);
                break;
        }
    });
}
```

When calling `addGitTagsNotFound()` with an array and a file, the input box only appears after what seems the rest of the function  `runGitConfigCheck()` finishes in the extension's parent `activate()` function.

I think I am just not understanding async/await properly, and since I'm synchronously appending to the config file, my guess is that it's blocking the input box from popping up.

Anyone that could help explain this to me, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stepped into this question while looking for similar issue.
Basically you should add async prefix to the addGitTagsNotFound function
and add await to each call to async function: vscode.window.showInputBox() and getUserInfo()

Working example:

```
async function getUserInfo(myplaceholder: string) {
    let userInputWindow =  await vscode.window.showInputBox({ placeHolder: myplaceholder, prompt: 'Here is the prompt' });
    return userInputWindow;
}

async function addGitTagsNotFound(tags: string[], configFile: fs.PathLike) {
    tags.forEach(function (tag) {
        switch(tag) {
            case 'user':
                let currentName = await getUserInfo('Message1')
                .then(function (result) {
                    return result;
                });
                let currentEmail = await getUserInfo('Message2')
                .then(function (result) {
                    return result;
                });
                console.log(currentEmail + ' ' currentEmail);
                break;
            case 'http':
                console.log('Adding config items for [http] tag');
                appendItemsToConfigFile(configFile, [`[${tag}]`,
                                                    '\tsslBackend=myconfig',
                                                    `\tsslCAInfo=${userProfile}\\path\\to\\folder`,
                                                    '\tproxy=http://myproxy.website.example:1234'], true);
                break;
            case 'https':
                console.log('Adding config items for [https] tag');
                appendItemsToConfigFile(configFile, [`[${tag}]`,
                                                    `\tsslCAInfo=${userProfile}\\path\\to\\folder`,
                                                    '\tproxy=proxy=http://myproxy.website.example:1234'], true);
                break;
            case 'core':
                console.log('Adding config items for [core] tag');
                appendItemsToConfigFile(configFile, [`[${tag}]`,
                                                    `\teditor=${userProfile}\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe -w`], true);
                break;
        }
    });
}
```